# Random images in php

Tags: php

I'm currently using this php code to to display images on php page with some text which is given by the user using input tag.

My php code is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/1.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
$font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
$text= $_GET['name']; 
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

This code is perfectly working I'm using `$_GET['name'];` to take input from the user as you can see I have selected a picture on which my text given by the user will appear any my image name is `1.jpg` I have more pictures in my library which I want that they should be selected randomly and print text on them given by the user my other pictures name are `2.jpg`,`3.jpg`,`4.jpg` hope you will find any solution for me.

Comment: Have a look at PHP's [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have 15 images, you can use:

```
$randomNumber = rand(1, 15);
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/' . $randomNumber . '.jpg');
```

Comment: `mt_rand` is better choice.

Comment: I was also going to suggest `mt_rand`, @walkingRed . All the answers (so far) here just use standard `rand` where `mt_rand` is, well, more random!

Comment: What is "random" @Martin?

Comment: hahaha random is when something is *almost* unpredictable. Although it has to be said for this topic, and this relatively small range of options the difference between `mt_rand` and `rand` is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers assume you always use numeric values for filenames but if you don't you could put the filenames in an array and use `array_rand()` to get a random filename from the array like this:

```
$image_files = array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg");
$image_filename = $image_files[array_rand($image_files)];
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/{$image_filename}");
```

Remember that `array_rand()` returns a random key from an array, not a value.

From here you could easily take it a step further and use `glob()` to get your filenames from a directory. When doing this you should take into account that `glob()` returns full paths so you will need to use `basename()` to get just the filename:

```
$image_files = glob("img/*.jpg");
$image_path = $image_files[array_rand($image_files)];
$image_filename = basename($image_path);
```

Comment: Nice to see one for picking random strings rather than random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$countImages = 10; // your last number
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/' . rand(1,$countImages). '.jpg');
```